# Make dynamically created radio buttons do a common event

Tags: c#, events, dynamic, radio-button

I have a button named Button1 in my form, and a text box named TexBox1.

I've written code such that when I click the button, a Radio button gets created with it'ss own name:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication7
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["Counter"] = 0;
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]); i++)
            {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                rb.GroupName = "GN1";
                rb.ID = i.ToString();
                rb.Text = "Button" + i.ToString(); 
                div.Controls.Add(rb);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(div);

            }
            ViewState["Counter"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]) + 1;


        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I click on the radio buttons, I want the TextBox1.Text to get the clicked radio button's text:

```
TextBox1.Text=rb.Text;
```

How can I make it apply to any radio button?

Answer (score 0):

Try subscribing to the `CheckedChanged` event, as you generate the `RadioButton` controls:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]); i++)
{
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
    rb.CheckedChanged += (s, a) => TextBox1.Text = ((RadioButton)s).Text;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi...thanks for the reply....Nothing happens when i click them...nothing goes to the text box, do i need to refresh anything, page, or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton btn = sender as RadioButton;
    textBox1.Text = btn.Text;
}
```

You need to attach it to the `Checked Changed` event when you creating your RadioBUtton

```
rb.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged;
```

Comment: Hi...thanks for the reply....i dont have function "private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) " when it is created dynamicaly...how can i make the buttons call this function automatically?

Comment: Write that function inside of your class,and when you creating your button use `rb.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged`

Comment: i did what u said, but it didnt do anything

Comment: I don't think you did.

Comment: @Selman22 i have put rb.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged; inside my <code> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)</code> function after <code>rb.Text = "Button"+i.ToString();</code> and made the function <code>private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)</code> as u said ... is it right?

Comment: @GrantWinney: did it but when i click on the radio buttons, it wont alert the breakpoint (wont execute <code>radioButton_CheckedChanged</code> function) and wont do anything.

Comment: @user3215839 it should work, try to change this line : `rb.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged;` to : `rb.Click += radioButton_CheckedChanged;`

Comment: @Selman22  : it gives error of "'System.web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton' does not contain a definiton for 'click' an no extension method WebForm1.aspx.cs and ...."

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
rb.OnMouseDown+= SomeMethod_Click;
```

And after you will have your method:

```
private void SomeMethod_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here your logic
}
```

Comment: Hello @user3215839 just Type: "rb." and then tap "ctrl+Space" to show the visual studio intellisense and there will be the events available like "OnMouseDown". I edit my answer with this event. [Here RabioButton on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx)  Greetings!